# Apache API proxy to nodejs

Tags: node.js, proxy, apache2

I have apache2 serving the page to users (its a PHP page). And then I have javascript connecting to the nodejs server.js file (on port 8443) And using socket.io to serve information and other stuff to the user.

But now I am trying to implement stripe payments on the site.

And the client needs to fetch a clientSecret using the code

```
fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
body: JSON.stringify(purchase)})
```

And in server.js I have

```
app.get("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
const { items } = req.body;
// Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
  currency: "usd"
});
res.send({
  clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
});
```

});

The problem I'm having is that the request https://mydomainname.com/create-payment-intent
is not working, I get a 404 error

However, it is working if the request has the nodejs port https://mydomainname.com:8443/create-payment-intent

so I'm trying to proxy the nodejs to https://mydomainname.com/api
so that i can use fetch("/api/create-payment-intent", in my code.

I have been trying a lot of different settings in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomainname.com.conf

```
  ProxyRequests off
    ProxypreserveHost on
    ProxyVia Full
    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8443/
```

and

```
 ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8443/
```

but I can't get it to work.

Either I get an
"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."
or a
"Not Found.
The requested URL was not found on this server."

I'm thankful for any information or help I can get! :)